# How to reduce size of result that mongo returns?

Tags: mongodb

With the same query (Aggregate), when I send this query on Robo3T, MongoDB returns in ~1 second. But in NodeJS, I'm using Mongoose to make query and with same above query, MongoDB response ~9 seconds

I used `explain('executionStats')` to check how query runs? Total execution time ~1s.

And in Robo3T, default number of record returns is 50, but NodeJS received ~2800 records and size result is 2Mb.

I think the result is too heavy, that why in NodeJS is slow because mongo returns full results

There any way to reduce result size or any way to reduce response time in NodeJS

Comment: Your question title seems to be misleading. Your goal is that you want to reduce the time that it takes to retrieve the 2800 docs? If that's the case then I don't think there's really enough information here for us to assist. For example, what is the bottleneck and how fast do you want the operation to be. What is the output of `.explain("allPlansExecution")` for the full query? By the way, 1 second for 50 documents seems pretty slow to begin with

Comment: @user20042973 actually, I see my query is fine. I just consider that with the same query, the response time of query without no limit record is too slow, but if I put the limit into last stage of pipeline, it return too fast. Is it a Object size of response issue? What do you think ?

Comment: The time it takes to transmit the data over the network and then for the app to process it is going to related to the total amount of data being received. So the fact that it takes 1 second to retrieve 2Mb makes the 9 seconds to retrieve (presumably) ~112Mb not too surprising. The data will be pulled in 16Mb batches meaning that the 112Mb of data will take about 7 or 8 round trips over the network which seems to match the increase in time quite well. It's still not clear to me what the bottleneck is or what you'd like to try to do about it though

Comment: @user20042973 my query have 4 stages, first one is $match query, second is a $group data, third is $lookup data from other collection, fourth is a $sort.

I'm watching to $lookup data and search how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the provided `limit()` function to limit the number of returned documents in a query. For example if you want to return 10 documents:

```
const result = await Model.find({}).limit(10).exec()
```

Also try using [indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/) to speed up execution of queries.

Comment: I created index for the query, and need to get all documents, so cannot use limit. If cannot resolve this issue, I have to limit :S